# Как померить время выполнения команды?

Tags: unix, время

Нужно померить время выполнение команды:

```
clock_t clock_beg = clock(); 
TCLIST * list = tcbdbrange(... some params...);
clock_t clock_end = clock();
```

Разница между `clock_beg` &  `clock_end` выдает 0

Comment: просто код выполняется быстрее, чем точность clock(). может профайлер использовать?

Comment: да там должно быть не так быстро...я думал наверно буду исп профайлер

Comment: а сами значения?

Answer (score 4):

Не мудрено. clock() меряет время в HZ (частоте систтемного таймера, обычно 100 раз в секунду)

Я обычно меряю так

```
/*
  время в миллисекундах

 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}
```

Если верите в микросекундные измерения, замените на

```
long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec;
```

На практике имеет смысл мерять **только** достаточно длинные циклы. Одиночным измерениям верить вообще нельзя.

Попрактикуйтесь, посмотрите сами,

Comment: ... а если у вас всего одна операция, выполните её в цикле хотя бы 1000 раз, и поделите время на 1000.

Comment: это сособ я знаю, цикл короткий - миллисекунды не подойдут.

Comment: 1000 раз не имеет смысла - так как реализовано кеширование

Comment: но все равно спасибо

Comment: @akalend, Вы можете, естественно, вызвать

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, ...)

или

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)

и получить  

    struct timespec {
        time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
        long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
    };

но повызывайте несколько раз (даже не с Вашим кэшированием) и Вы увидите, что это обман. 

Реально, короткие интервалы в *живой* системе не измеряются.

Comment: надо было измерить разные вызовы АПИ и выбрать лучший, вроде как предложенный способ подходит
спасибо