# Как подсчитать время работы функции?

Tags: c, windows, время

Сначала использовал структуру 
`clock_t` , но функция срабатывала слишком быстро и результатом был ноль.Потом использовал то, что было посоветованно в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/171096/258486) вопросе,но это всё годится только для unix, а как тогда сосчитать время по-другому?
UPD:

```
int i = 0;
int sum1 = 0;
clock_t start1, stop1;
start1 = clock();
while (i++ < 100) 
{

    DrawQueue = wallstopointer(labirint);
}
stop1 = clock();
 sum1 = stop1 - start1;
printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t%f  seconds were spent", (double)(sum1/100) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // приведение типов
```

Действовал,как советовали в комментариях , всё равно 0

Comment: запускайте функцию много-много раз и потом делите.

Comment: @KoVadim,делить на количество запусков?

Comment: В WinAPI есть для этого [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: время, за которое выполнялась много раз функция на кол-во этих выполнений

Comment: согласно обновлению вопроса. Видимо, 100 слишком мало. И лучше использовать классический for, в Вашем варианте не видно, чем инициализировано `i`.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что в `(double)(sum1/100) `  одна пара скобок лишняя (вторая пара). Вы уверены, что не получаете 0 еще при делении на 100? Чему обычно равно `sum1`?

Comment: лишняя, но лучше написать просто явно `sum1/100.0`

Comment: Начала выводить 0.000080, довольно странно, ведь в этой функции  находится два вложенных цикла , и каждый цикл имеет 125 итераций

Comment: Выводите как %g, а не %f.

Comment: @Elvin 80 мкс - вполне обычное время для мелких функций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для точного измерения времени (в том числе), в Windows существуют [performance counters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal). Конкретно для вашего примера это выглядит так:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ProcessError() {
  printf("Error %08X\n", ::GetLastError());
}

void MyFunction() {
  unsigned long long int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) sum += i + 1;
}

int main() {
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)) ProcessError();
  double frequency = (double)freq.QuadPart;

  LARGE_INTEGER tm0;
  if (!::QueryPerformanceCounter(&tm0)) ProcessError();

  // В этом месте вызывается функция, для которой
  // нужно измерить время выполнения.
  MyFunction();

  LARGE_INTEGER elaps;
  if (!::QueryPerformanceCounter(&elaps)) ProcessError();
  elaps.QuadPart -= tm0.QuadPart;

  double elapsed = (double)elaps.QuadPart;
  elapsed *= 1.0e3;       // Нам нужно время в миллисекундах
                          //elapsed *= 1.0e6;     // ...или в микросекундах
  elapsed /= frequency;

  printf("Elapsed time: %7.3fms\n", elapsed);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему-то ругается на ProcessError();

Comment: @Elvin - Потому что вы сами должны ее определить. Свою функцию обработки ошибки, или `throw/catch`, или что хотите. Что вы хотите сделать, если `QueryPerformanceCounter` вернет ошибку? Вот это и пишите. Ну или можете вместо `if` просто написать вызов `QueryPerformanceCounter`, ошибка в принципе достаточно маловероятна.

Comment: ,почему-то все условия проваливаются и моя функция не вызывается

Comment: @Elvin, после проваленного условия поставьте `DWORD dr = ::GetLastError();`. Что возвращается в `dr`?

Comment: if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)) 
  frequency = (double)freq.QuadPart;
 DWORD dr = ::GetLastError();  Записывается нуль. Он еще ругался на double frequency ,который после первого условия объявлялся , поэтому я frequency объявил перед всем замером функции

Comment: @Elvin, `GetLastError` возвращает 0 если функция отработала успешно, то есть возвратила `TRUE`. С чего вы взяли что условие проваливается? Я эту программку запустил (добавил только функции `MyFunction` и `ProcessError`), все работает.  `MyFunction` просто складывала миллион целых. Что значит "ругался на double frequency"?? Что именно компилятор сказал? Там только в последнем printf лишняя скобка, а так все компилируется.

Comment: ,if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq))  и if (!::QueryPerformanceCounter(&elaps))  проваливаются , не дают создать переменную frequency  и вызвать функцию соответсвенно

Comment: ,понял, там не нужен '!'.Один вопрос: эта функция считает тики процессора? То есть на видеокарте не посчитает время работы kernel ?

Comment: @Elvin, я вообще не понимаю что у вас происходит. Я заменил текст примера на рабочую проверенную программу. Программа приведена полностью, можно компилировать и запускать. Я ее запустил в [онлайн компиляторе](https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual), и все прекрасно отработало. Да, тики процессора, про видеокарты ничего не знаю.

Comment: ,у меня всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: [Полезная инфа о QueryPerformanceCounter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps). Обратите внимание, возможные вопросы о барьерах (памяти, команд) при доступе к TSC для  out-of-order chips полностью игнорированы. Вопрос -- а какой именно интервал именно мы считаем?