# Сильно ли влияет memcpy на получаемое время работы функции?

Tags: c

Задав  вопрос [Как подсчитать время работы функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907416/258486), мне посоветовали много-много раз запускать свою функцию,чтобы получить время её работы.

```
                int kkk = 0;
                int copyofb[N+5];
                memcpy(copyofb, a, N + 5);
                start = clock();
            int* pointer;
            int* pointer1;
            while (kkk < 100)
            {
for (pointer = &a[1], pointer1 = &b[1]; pointer <= (a+*(a+0)); pointer++, pointer1++)
                {
                    c = c + *pointer - *pointer1 + 10;
                    *pointer = c % 10;
                    c = (c < 10) ? -1 : 0;
                }
                while (( *(pointer+ *(a + 0)) == 0 && *(pointer + 0) > 1)) *(pointer+0) = *(pointer + 0) - 1;
                kkk++;
                if (kkk >= 100)
                    break;
                memcpy(a, copyofb, N + 5);
            }
            stop = clock();
```

Причиной создания такого костыля с постоянным копированием изначального значения в массив **а** ,является то,что значение,посчитанное в первый раз уже изменит массив **a** ,но мне нужно именно сосчитать с какой скоростью вычитались изначальные значения, а не измененные.Поэтому у меня вопрос: **memcpy** сильно влияет на время при N=10000?Если сильно влияет, то как зациклить по-другому?
UPD:
Сделал,как советовали в комментариях

```
int kkk = 0;
        int copyofb[N + 5];
        memcpy(copyofb, a, N + 5);
        clock_t start, stop;
        start = clock();
        //writelong(a);
        while (kkk < 10000)
        {
            memcpy(a, copyofb, N + 5);
            kkk++;
            if (kkk >= 10000)
                break;
        }
        stop = clock();
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t%f  seconds were spent", (double)(stop - start) /10000/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // приведение типов
```

Время ноль, значит не влияет никак.

Comment: А вы зациклите только копирование memcpy 10000 раз и посмотрите, насколько оно влияет...

Comment: Я же в том вопросе написал вам код для измерения времени с точностью до наносекунд практически.

Comment: @freim,я понимаю,я просто не умею пользоваться winapi и не успею с ним разобраться за короткое время.У вас есть что-нибудь по этому поводу для полного новичка?

Comment: Да я же вам написал готовый код, там даже разбираться не надо. Написать только функцию для обработки ошибки (или вообще убрать обработку). И все.